# Draw graph from datagridview values Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, graph, datagridview

There are two columns that I want to plot a graph from. The number of rows in the data grid view is constantly increasing so the curve on the line should propagate correspondingly. How do you do that?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I have no need to do this. But if you want to do it, feel free to do it.

Comment: waste of space in my comment section

Comment: If you are not able to paste your try and which problems you got, your post is a waste of bytes. We are not a coding service for you.

Comment: Can you share any of your code, if code is involved?  Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: There should not be a comment section if you don't have a proper question to ask. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to do that.